# sharedURLCache getting cleared by AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer, nsurlcache

The shared URLCache works correctly in testing. As soon as I load AVPlayer though, my request no longer pull from cache. Is this intended behavior? What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: How do you get URLCache work with AVPlayer? Do you go through AVAssetResourceLoader?

Comment: As far as I'm aware it is used by default. If you're trying to change properties of the cache you should be able to access the instance using URLCache.shared

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've come up with is not using the sharedURLCache and instead setting up my own URLCache:

```
static let appURLSession: NSURLSession = {
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    config.URLCache = NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: 10 * 1024 * 1024, diskCapacity: 50 * 1024 * 1024, diskPath: nil)
    return NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: _singleton, delegateQueue: nil)
}()
```

If anyone else has a better answer or explanation I'm all ears.